# connect is not available as command of consul

Tags: consul

**Query**

> ~$ consul connect proxy -sidecar-for socat

**Output:**

`usage: consul [--version] [--help] <command> [<args>]`

Available commands are:

```
agent          Runs a Consul agent
configtest     Validate config file
event          Fire a new event
exec           Executes a command on Consul nodes
force-leave    Forces a member of the cluster to enter the "left" state
info           Provides debugging information for operators
join           Tell Consul agent to join cluster
keygen         Generates a new encryption key
keyring        Manages gossip layer encryption keys
leave          Gracefully leaves the Consul cluster and shuts down
lock           Execute a command holding a lock
maint          Controls node or service maintenance mode
members        Lists the members of a Consul cluster
monitor        Stream logs from a Consul agent
reload         Triggers the agent to reload configuration files
rtt            Estimates network round trip time between nodes
version        Prints the Consul version
watch          Watch for changes in Consul
```

Comment: Trying to learn consul from:- https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/getting-started/connect

Comment: consul kv is also not available.  How can i update this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Consul are you using? You can check this with `consul --version`.

The `consul kv` commands were introduced in version [0.7.1](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#071-november-10-2016). Consul Connect was added in version [1.2.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-june-26-2018).

Both should be available if you are using a recent version.

Comment: What common version should I use to have all these functionalities of consul ?

Comment: Anything newer will have these. I recommend using the latest version, 1.7.2.